How do I fix this error importing Ragas evaluation chain
I am having trouble importing Ragas evaluation chain in colab notebook
from ragas.langchain.evalchain import RagasEvaluatorChain


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
----> 1 from ragas.langchain.evalchain import RagasEvaluatorChain

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_openai/chat_models/azure.py in <module>
      7 
      8 import openai
----> 9 from langchain_core.language_models.chat_models import LangSmithParams
     10 from langchain_core.outputs import ChatResult
     11 from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import Field, SecretStr, root_validator


ImportError: cannot import name 'LangSmithParams' from 'langchain_core.language_models.chat_models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py)


fixed it by fixing the version of ragas to 0.0.11
